# A free() needed after malloc on mcu (even when the array/pointer is always in use)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

Alright, I am quite the beginner at C, so I might not understand everything yet, so here I go:

We need to program a stm32f0 using c without any hal libraries. For an exercise, we needed to change the example usart code from sequential to interrupt driven (for the receiving part). Now that wasn't too difficult. Another assignment was to add a fifo buffer. (actual assignment stated we needed to use a fixed buffer size of about 100 characters). I wanted to implement a dynamic buffer size. A bit of googling gave me the answer to use a pointer and use malloc to allocate memory for the required characters. So I did this:

```
volatile char *fifo_char_buffer;
void USART_init(int bufsize){
    fifo_char_buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof *fifo_char_buffer);
    //setting bunch of registers for usart1
}
//functions for writing/reading fifobuffer
```

It's all working fine and dandy on the microcontroller. But I started reading some more about malloc, and I found out that it's more or less mandatory to do a free after the malloc.

Now my question is: since this buffer in its current state will never be cleared all at once, and will be used continuously until you literally shut down the device, do I really need to free that pointer? To my, possibly limited, knowledge, every time you restart the MCU it will just do all the allocation again, right?

Comment: You call `free()` only when you no longer need that memory.

Comment: I would be very careful with the dynamic allocation on the uC. Usually heap is tiny, and you need to link a lots of libraries as well. If it is the uC you should consider another ways.

Comment: is it C or C++ (don't cast return of malloc in C, you have to cast it in C++) ? I suppose it's C, edited tag.

Comment: All to be said: On such systems, don't use `malloc` & friends at all. It typically is not even implemented or maybe just a stub. How do you know, as you don't even check for errors? If you need that buffer all the time, why dynamically alloc at all and not use a static array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that a lot of non-embedded programs without an infinite loop also don't call `free`, they just call `exit`, and rely on the OS resource tracking mechanism, but such code has to be reworked if reused in a library, so bad practice here.

*But* on embedded systems, it's perfecly okay to allocate memory, then start the main loop (which never ends unless it crashes or is manually rebooted).

Some extra rules (sometimes enforced by the OS) even prevent you to call `malloc` once the program is in "running" state.

So no need for `free` ever in this kind of program.

And yes, when you reboot your device, the OS calls your program from a clean slate, and the init process allocates memory again, and so on.

Comment: If the main loop exists which is not obvious.

Comment: "this buffer in its current state will never be cleared all at once, and will be used continuously until you literally shut down the device". That seems implied that there's some infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 You can pretty much guarantee it exists, a microcrontroller wont be "microcontrolling" anything if it's program ends.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the kind of answer that I was looking for, somewhere it felt wrong not using a free (probably because everywhere where I went there was someone who mentioned that a free was necessary), but logically speaking, I wouldn't even know where I would put the free effectively, so I just left it out. Now I more or less know for sure that I did the right thing!

Comment: @Havenard unless is fully interrupt driven & some hardware (Cortex micros for example) have special hardware features to archive it (SLEEPONEXIT)

Comment: the ones which tell you that free is always necessary are reading too much books and are not in the open coding stuff that isn't on a PC :)

Comment: Bare-metal embedded systems rarely use `exit` either. They typically run an infinit loop (somewhere, possibly in the RTOS) until power-off.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out previously, a free is not strictly necessary. However, for debugging and maintenance purposes it is useful to have the corresponding free. If your malloc debugging tools say that you have no outstanding memory, you know that you don't have a certain class of errors.